# Regex to extract string between two sets of underscores

Tags: regex

I have been trying to extract a string for a directory path that contains multiple underscores as delimiters.

I'm [trying](https://regex101.com/r/gVOqMw/1) on regex101 to extract `foobar` but can only get `_pdf-documents_`

**regex**

```
_([^_]+)_
```

**directory path**

```
/data/documents/2020/05/07/2020-05-07-12_pdf-documents_foobar_hour.abc.defg.log
```

Comment: Split string with `_` and get the `results[2]` item. What is your programming language?

Comment: I need the regex and using in python.

Comment: Good, but it is not clear what your regex engine is, what method you are using it in.

Answer (score 0):

If [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is ok, then :

```
echo '/data/documents/2020/05/07/2020-05-07-12_pdf-documents_foobar_hour.abc.defg.log' | 
awk -F'_' '{print $3}'
```

### Output

```
foobar
```

Or like said [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) in comments, split like I do in another language, this is the most simple, maintainable, readable and reliable solution

Answer (score 0):

If you work only with this string you can use this `_([^_p]+)_`

Comment: Close but I need **foobar** without the underscores.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
.*_([^_]+)_.*
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not  a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can `edit` to add additional info, or links to documentation.